# How to save value and show it on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# ASP.NET WebSite, and in one form I have to register information for an Id displayed into a dropdown input, the problem is that I can do this steps a lot of times, so my question is how can I save the selected Id and show it after postback? I know that I can use:

```
Page_Load
   if (IsPostBack)
```

But I don't know exactly what to do, so I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm trying:

Function onclick to register my data after my success message:

```
Session["ID"] = id.Value;
Session["IDN"] = this.alertatxt.Text;
```

Page Load

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
   id.Value = Session["ID"].ToString();
   this.alertatxt.Text = Session["IDN"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: You need to store it somewhere - read up on and understand Session State, View State and Application State: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/de41d6/view-state-vs-session-state-vs-application-state/

Comment: Take a look to my edit, that was I'm trying to use

Comment: Did you verify IsPostBack is being ran?

Comment: @triswill227 I put a message inside if (IsPostBack) but this message do not appears.

Comment: @triswill227 Now my message is displayed, so my if (IsPostBack) in executed

Comment: Use  Page_PreRender instead of Page_Load. Event handlers like button click are run after Load but before PreRender, so if you put a message in after button click, prerender will display at the same time, not after one more postback

Comment: So if the message doesnt appear then either you are outputting your message wrong, its not being stored properly, or IsPostBack isnt even being called. Look into debugging using breakpoints http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/breakpoints/